# Automatically convert selected data from latin2 to utf8

Tags: php, encoding

I'm trying to move some data from one database to another. Unfortunately one has latin2 encoding and other one uses utf8. Is there any possibility to do some automatic conversion of encoding latin2->utf-8? Or my only option is using iconv() on every single data selected from latin2 database?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [recipe](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Convert_latin1_to_UTF-8_in_MySQL) and adapt it to Latin2 of course ;-)